# How do I evaluate this logarithm expression: $10 \log_{10} (x/y) = -20$?

Tags: logarithms

I *think* the answer for this is 0.01, but I'm not sure.  Could someone explain the steps in solving the following for $(x/y)$:

$$10 \log_{10} (x/y) = -20$$

I've tried putting $\frac{-20}{10 \log_{10}}$ in Wolfram Alpha, but the answer doesn't look like what I was expecting.

Comment: The answer $0.01$, or equivalently $10^{-2}$, is correct.

Comment: it seems that  we have  $log_{10}(x/y)$ right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $z=x/y$ so you have
$$
\begin{split}
10 \log z &= -20 \\
\log z &= -2 \\
10^{\log z} &= 10^{-2} \\
z &= 0.01
\end{split}
$$
assuming your log was base 10. If it was base $e$, the last 2 steps are
$$
\begin{split}
e^{\log z} &= e^{-2} \\
z &= e^{-2}
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 3):

divide both members by 10.

--> log (x/y) = -2

--> 10^-2 = x/y

--> 0.01 = x/y

Comment: oops, was that second ten a base on the logarithm or a coefficient of (x/y)?

Comment: your answer is correct my friend +1

Answer (score 1):

ok  we have following thing

$log_{10}(x/y)=-2$

or

$(x/y)=10^{-2}$